# How to prove that the matrix of a symmetric bilinear form is symmetric

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, bilinear-form, symmetric-matrices

A bilinear form $B:V \times V \rightarrow K$ is said to be symmetric if $B(\mathbf{v,w}) = B(\mathbf{w,v}) \ \forall \mathbf{v,w} \in V,$ where $V$ is a vector space over some field $K.$

A matrix $A$ is said to be symmetric $\iff$ $\langle Ax, y \rangle = \langle x, Ay \rangle \ \forall x, y \in V.$

When I try to prove this using those two facts, I come across issues such as doesn't $V$ need to be an inner product space to be able to define the notion of the standard inner product (dot product)? Also, (real) dot products map to $\mathbb{R}$ and not an arbitrary field $K.$

Comment: The dot product of two vectors in $K^n$ is $K$-valued. How could it be otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, it's an important observation that the whole linear algebra formalism requires the numbers to have addition, subtraction, multiplication and division with any nonzero. 
It means that *all works the same way* when the scalars (coefficients, matrix entries, etc.) are taken from an 'over arbitrary field' $K$ in place of the reals $\Bbb R$.

This definition of a matrix being symmetric indeed presumes an inner product, but it can be reformulated simply in terms of the matrix entries: 
Apply the equation to the standard basis vectors $x=e_i,\,y=e_j$. Since the $\langle Ae_i,e_j\rangle$ is the $j$th coordinate of the $i$th column of $A$, and $\langle e_i,Ae_j\rangle$ is the $i$th coordinate of the $j$th column, it indeed means that the matrix is symmetric:
$$a_{ij}=a_{ji}$$
In the context of matrices, this definition (or its transpose form: $A^T=A$) *doesn't require* a priori any inner product, neither any vector space.

However, once we *fix a basis* $(e_i)$ in a finite dimensional vector space $V$, it automatically induces an inner product (by the usual formula with coordinates), in which $(e_i)$ becomes orthonormal. 
In your first paragraph, there is no basis and no inner product fixed. 
On the other hand, when we use matrices (with entries from $K$), we might automatically associate the vector spaces $K^n$ with their standard basis and inner product.